# How do you exclude folders on get operation for sourcecontrol in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a cruisecontrol.net project which currently doesn't monitor a source safe project. It is forced manually.  Within the source control block however I want to be able to exclude the 'get' operation of a certain folder.  I know there is a ExclusionFilter feature on a source control block in the config file, but I think that this excludes the sub folder from being monitored not from being retrieved from the repository.

Can anyone confirm this is the case, or help me find out how I can achieve this? 
I'm using CCNet 1.4 and SourceSafe

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting round this by using a Multi source control block. I then had multiple  entries with different sub-projects underneath. This has the effect of being able to force a build and select for example sub-folders: Folder1, Folder3 but not Folder2.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the filter only allows you to prevent changes in specific folders/files from triggering the build. What are you using for source control? We happen to be using AccuRev, and there is a straightforward way to configure the build "workspace" to exclude parts of the code base. I'd expect that most modern source control systems would have a similar capability, although I wouldn't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

We are using SourceSafe. If there is no ability to exclude certain folders, can the source safe block be configured to perform a get on specific folders rather than the whole tree structure?

Answer (score 0):

We are on TFS, not SourceSafe, but hopefully SourceSafe has something similar. The way we do this is through our workspace mappings and cloaking folders we don't want. Cloaking has two benefits, it prevents the get, and when CruiseControl asks for modifications any Cloaked folder does not report them, so I do not even need to use the filtered source control it just happens.